# Pointers to an Array In C

Tags: c, pointers

So my book is explaining me pointers to an array using ts example

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int s[4][2] = {
        {1234,56},{1212,33},{1434,80},{1312,78}
    };
    int(*p)[2];
    int i, j, * pint;
    for (i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
    {
        p = &s[i];
        pint = (int*)p;
        printf("\n");
        for (j = 0; j<= 1; j++)
        {
            printf("%d ", *(pint + j));
        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

The output is Given as

```
1234 56
1212 33
1434 80
1312 78
```

No issue I am getting the same output.
My question is **what was the need of using another pointer *pint* ?**
Why can't we directly use ***P***?

So When I tried to do it using ***P*** directly it *didn't work*

```
printf("%d ", *(p + j));
```

I got garbage values in output, *Why is this happening?*
I also tried printing ***p*** and ***pint*** they are the same.

Comment: `q + j` depends on the size of `*q`.  The size of `*p` is that of an array of 2 ints, while the size of `*pint` is the size of one int.  Try `printf("%p: %p: %p: %p", p, pint, p+1, pint + 1);` to see the difference.

Comment: Oh thank you, now I understood the difference in them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although `p` and `pint` have the same value, `p + 1` and `pint + 1` do not.  `p + 1` is the same as `(char *)p + sizeof *p`, and `pint + 1` is the same as `(char *)pint + sizeof *pint`.  Since the size of the object pointed to is different, the arithmetic gives different results.

Answer (score 0):

The pointer `p` is declared like

```
int(*p)[2];
```

So dereferencing the pointer expression with the pointer in this call of printf

```
printf("%d ", *(p + j));
```

you will get the j-th "row" of the type `int[2]` of the two dimensional array that in turn will be implicitly converted to a pointer of the type `int *` that will point to the first element of the j-th "row".

So instead of outputting elements of each row you will output first elements of each row that moreover results in undefined behavior when `i` will be greater than `2`.